# How to use methods from other class to add a card (blackjack game)?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to work on my first program, a blackjack assignment.  I've built a bunch of methods in my BlackJackDeck class, and now I want to start implementing them in my program class, but I'm getting a an argument out of range exception when I try to add a card.  I've tried doing a userHand.Add, I've tried doing a userHand[0] =, but I'm just not getting this implemented.  I'm guessing the big problem is in my addCard method in my BlackJackDeck class.  I've also tried using Cards[0] instead of the .Count method.  Cards is a list of random cards at this point.

BlackJackDeck.cs

```
 public Card addCard()
    {

        Card cardToAdd = Cards[Cards.Count-1];
        Cards.RemoveAt(Cards.Count-1);
        return cardToAdd;
    }
```

Program CS

```
 class Program
    {
        static List<Card> userHand;
        static List<Card> dealerHand;
        static BlackJackDeck blackJackDeck;



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            blackJackDeck = new BlackJackDeck();
            blackJackDeck.shuffleCards();
            DealHand();
        }
        static void DealHand() {
            userHand = new List<Card>();
            userHand[0] = (blackJackDeck.addCard());
            userHand[1] = (blackJackDeck.addCard());
            Console.WriteLine("Card1: {0} of {1}", userHand[0].Face, userHand[0].Suit);
            Console.WriteLine("Card2: {0} of {1}", userHand[1].Face, userHand[1].Suit);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe when you try to add first cart Cards[Cards.Count-1], this would be Cards[-1] which is error

Comment: I tried, just not so good with the debugger yet

Comment: You have to add items, something like `userHand,Add(blackJackDeck.addCard());`

Comment: Watch this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-HdLtqEOog

Comment: thanks, I'll bookmark that for tomorrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is not being thrown in `addCard()`. The problem is with `userHand`. Since the list is empty, there is nothing at index `0` to which it can assign the right-hand-side value, so it throws an exception. *Range* here refers to the range of indices for which the List is defined; for an empty list, the range is also an empty set, hence the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` where the Argument in question is the index used (`0` in this case). To add elements to a List use the [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
userHand = new List<Card>();
userHand.Add(blackJackDeck.addCard());
userHand.Add(blackJackDeck.addCard());
```

Without seeing how `BlackJackDeck.Cards` is initialized, I can't say that `addCard()` won't cause an Exception, but the above should at least solve your problem with `DealHand()`.

Comment: I know I tried that before, but I think I may have had capitalization issues.  working now, thanks!